# Fold a pre-defined syntax region in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, folding

I am using this [php syntax file](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/php.vim/blob/48fc7311fa07c2b83888e7a31fae03118bae720b/syntax/php.vim#L585) and I want to fold the phpdoc comments.

This syntax file [already creates](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/php.vim/blob/48fc7311fa07c2b83888e7a31fae03118bae720b/syntax/php.vim#L585) a syn region for phpdoc comments. The relevant code is

```
syn region phpDocComment   start="/\*\*" end="\*/" keepend contains=phpCommentTitle,phpDocTags,phpTodo,@Spell
```

Now my question is how to enable folding for this syn region which is already created in my `~/.vimrc` file?

I added the following line in my `~/.vimrc` but it didn't work.

```
syn region phpDocComment   start="/\*\*" end="\*/" keepend contains=phpCommentTitle,phpDocTags,phpTodo,@Spell fold
```

Comment: Why don't you do that in that syntax file instead?

Comment: The reason why I don't want to make the changes directly in that file is because it is not maintained by me and I am including it as a bundle using Vundle. If I directly change it and if the author releases an update then my changes would be lost.

Comment: No, you could fork the plugin and merge further "official" changes or, better, send pull requests to its author.

Comment: I didn't wanted to maintain my own fork with only this change, but sending pull request is a good idea. Let me check with the author if he is interested in receiving a pull request. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `:scriptnames` output. Your `~/.vimrc` is executed at the very beginning, whereas a syntax script is only loaded after Vim startup, loading a buffer, filetype detection, etc.

If you need to augment a syntax script and don't want to modify the script itself (which isn't recommended unless you're the author - you'd have to re-apply your changes after every script update), the right place to do this is via the *after* directory. Put your `:syntax` command into `~/.vim/after/syntax/php.vim`.

As this only extends the original syntax rules, you may have to remove the original one first (also in the after file):

```
syn clear phpDocComment
```